# How can I use the variables of the Future<List> in the build? In this case it shows undefined name

Tags: flutter, future

[Flutter Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqqAx.png)

I tried a couple of ways but I thik so that I am missing a particular method or function here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include your code as _text_ rather than an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use FutureBuilder.

Since you did not include full code, you have to adapt this to your purpose

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final Future<String> _calculation = Future<String>.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 2),
    () => 'Data Loaded',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getRequest, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.check_circle_outline,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}'),
              ),
            ];
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              ),
            ];
          } else {
            children = const <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              ),
            ];
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main points in your question:

1. How do I show Future values in Widgets? A/ You may use a `FutureBuilder`:

> Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction
> with a Future.
>
> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.

with the future being the method or the API request itself (I'm not using any architecture so you don't get lost)

and 2. Why am I getting the undefined name in "questions" variable? A/ That's because you're declaring that variable: `List<Question> questions` outside the method where you're calling it: "the build method", you could use a `FutureBuilder` as I said before or a `StatefulWidget` and calling an async method retrieving the data and updating the State of your list.